# Azure search, filter and order by collection

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Want to use azure search for a search on e-commerce site. The part that I'm struggling with is product stock. Each product has stock saved for several shop departments. Client can select one or two departments as a search filter. Is it possible to order products by stock in specific departments? And is it possible to filter products that have stock > 0 in for example department with id 2 or 4? I know that fields of type Collection(Edm.String) cannot be sortable, but maybe is there any other way of implementing this case? One way could be to take products from search applying all filters despite stock and then order by stock (or filter stock > 0) on the server side, but it can be slow and inefficient especially for large set of products. Other approach could be to save stock for each department in separate field but currently we have 200 departments and the number can be higher. Wouldn't it be too many fields?

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: When you say "order products by stock in specific departments", do you mean that more than one department will be selected in that case? If so, what exactly would you want to order products by, since there would be more than one stock value per product? Would you want to order on the maximum stock value? Minimum stock value? Something else?

Comment: Hi, user will select department A and then department B. In such case system should order results by stock in department A and then by stock in department B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to approach this, each with different tradeoffs.

1. If you model the stock for each department as a separate field, then you can easily order by the different departments just by changing the order in which the fields appear in the `orderby` parameter. However, Azure Search has a limit of 1000 fields per index (this limit drops down to 100 for Basic tier), so this approach might not scale as you add more departments.
2. You could have two string collection fields, one for all the departments where a product is available, and another one of the same length containing the number in stock for each department. If you model it this way, you can formulate a query that filters products by department, but you can't filter products by department by stock level; you'd have to do this in your application code. Since there is no way to order by collections, you'd also have to do any sorting in your application code.
3. If you're interested in evaluating the new [Complex Types feature](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/6670910-modelling-complex-types-in-indexes) that is currently in private preview, you can model departments and stock levels as a collection of objects. This allows you to filter products by departments and stock level (for example, `$filter=departments/any(d: (d/departmentId eq 2 or d/departmentId eq 4) and d/stock gt 0)`), but you'd still need to do the ordering in your application code.
4. Probably the most robust solution would be to have an index specifically for filtering/ordering by stock level. Instead of one document per product, you'd have one document per product per department. Then the stock level of that product in that department would just be an integer field, and you can sort and filter on it easily. This has the added bonus of not returning any departments that don't match the filter (approaches 2 and 3 can't filter out departments like this).

Comment: Thank you for answer! I think I will go with the first approach. 3rd one seems to be really interesting but without ordering is also problematic. With 4rd one I see some drawbacks. If I would need to search prduct by name or by some other field and order by stock than I need to store product name (and all others searchable fields) in this extra index per product per department. Another thing is filtering products available in two departments - If product will be available in both departments than I will need to make a distinct on the server side.

Comment: You wrote about 4rd approach 'This has the added bonus of not returning any departments that don't match the filter' but can't I do it with first approach? If I will want to take only products available in first department that will be stored for example as field 'dep-1' than I could make a filter to return only documents that match filter and also I could specify that from all stock fields I want to return only field 'dep-1'. I'm new in azure search so please forgive me if I'm wrong in any of me assumptions.

Comment: @mrrobot You're right, I missed that case. You can use $select to include only the department field(s) you care about in the results. I would still recommend approach 4 over approach 1 though, as it will be much easier to add/remove departments. It's not unusual to have multiple indexes with different views on your source data to satisfy different query patterns.